# Find elements in a collection beginning with 16:xx:xx in mongoDB

Tags: mongodb

If I want to get the elements with the Date that is at 16:xx:xx
**db.collection.find({"Date":/^16:/})**
The following elements should be:
2020-09-24 16:00:00
2020-06-10 16:01:30
2019-02-14 16:38:00
How can I get the result like this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As solution you can project your date to string before do search, and after it you can easy use regexp for implement search, It is simple example

```
db.collection.aggregate(
[
    {
        $project: {
            "d":  { $dateToString: {format: "%Y-%m-%d", date: "$mydate"}},key:1
        }
    }  ,
    {
        $match: {
            d: /^16:/i
        }
    }
]
)
```